# How to subtract two doubles?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, subtraction

I want to get IRQ in Spark. How can I subtract two values (double or int)?

I tried the code below but only got error:

```
scala> Q1
res103: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [11.09314]
scala> Q3
res104: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [34.370419]
scala> val IRQ = Math.abs(Q3-Q1)
<console>:43: error: value - is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       val IRQ = Math.abs(Q3-Q1)
```

Comment: You'd have to update the value in the row, theres no way to subtract entire rows (I'm just rephrasing the error).

Comment: `[11.09314]` looks like an array, handle it like that i.e. `Math.abs(Q3(0) - Q1(0))`?

Comment: You should probably read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getDouble%28int%29), method `getDouble` might help.

Comment: It didnt work. `Math.abs(Q3(0) - Q1(0))`

Comment: The answer provided here is correct ! You can make some effort accepting it at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val IQR = Math.abs(Q3.getDouble(0) - Q1.getDouble(0))
```

See the docs for `Row` interface [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getDouble%28int%29).

Comment: I did below, but got no lucks.

Comment: `scala> val IRQ  = Math.abs(Q3.getDouble(0) - Q1.getDouble(0))
java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: and `scala> val IRQ : Double  = Math.abs(Q3.getDouble(0) - Q1.getDouble(0))
java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: this as well `scala> val IRQ : Double  = Math.abs(Q3(0).asInstanceOf[Double] - Q1(0).asInstanceOf[Double])
java.lang.ClassCastException
`

Comment: do you know what datatype is inside, maybe it's a string?

Comment: can you do `Q1.schema()` and see what's in there?